# Given a sequence $\left(\tfrac{x}{p}\right),\left(\tfrac{x+1}{p}\right),\dots,$ how hard it is to find an $x$ that fits?

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

Let $p$ be some 1000-bit prime number.

Given a sequence $1$'s and $-1$'s
$$\left(\tfrac{x}{p}\right),\left(\tfrac{x+1}{p}\right),\dots,\left(\tfrac{x+80}{p}\right)$$ how hard it is to find an $x \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ if $p$ is prime?

Here $\left(\tfrac{x}{p}\right)$ denotes Legendre symbol, which can be defined as
$\left(\tfrac{x}{p}\right) := x^{(p-1)/2} \bmod p$.

Comment: I found [this](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/182.pdf) which partially answers the problem.

Comment: Presumably (and probably provably) about one out of every $2^{81}$ integers $x$ should work, and testing any particular $x$ is quite fast; but the expected number of trials $2^{81}$ is pretty large in practice.